# Python access all the second elements in list and added them to a new list

Tags: python, list

How I can access all the second elements and added them to a new list.
I want the result to be [ Airport, Temple U, Warminster,...]

here is my list:

```py
my_list_of_stuff = [['R4S=01:25', 'Airport', '3B', ' 2 LATE', 'LOCAL                    ', '437   ', '<_NEXT_MSG>01:55', 'Airport', '3B', 'ON TIME', 'LOCAL                    ', '9439  ', '<_NEXT_MSG>02:25', 'Airport', '3B', 'ON TIME', 'LOCAL                    ', '441   ', '<_NEXT_MSG>02:55', 'Airport', '3B', 'ON TIME', 'LOCAL                    ', '9443  ', ''], ['R4N=01:35', 'Temple U', '2A', ' 3 LATE', 'LOCAL                    ', '9434  ', '<_NEXT_MSG>02:05', 'Warminster', '2A', 'ON TIME', 'LOCAL                    ', '436   ', '<_NEXT_MSG>02:35', 'Temple U', '2A', 'ON TIME', 'LOCAL                    ', '9438  ', '<_NEXT_MSG>03:05', 'Warminster', '2A', 'ON TIME', 'LOCAL                    ', '440   ', '']]
```

I get this Error"IndexError: list index out of range"
here is my code:

```py
trains = []
for i in range(len(my_list_of_stuff)):
        A = [x[1] for x in my_list_of_stuff]
        trains.append(A)
```

Comment: thank you guys but I get an error says "list index out of range"

Comment: Did you try exactly what we did? You used list comprehension where it can't be used. Put that exact code that I had written, and it will work. It actually goes through the entire list, ie each sublist, and gets the second element. So, consider the `for x in my_list_of_stuff` as getting each sublist, and then the `x[1]` to get the second element there.

Answer (score 0):

just zip it to transpose

`transposed = zip(*my_list_of_stuff)`

then you can just select the 1th column

`transposed[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to achieve this:

```
current_list = [['R4S=01:25', 'Airport', '3B', ' 2 LATE', 'LOCAL                    ', '437   ', '<_NEXT_MSG>01:55', 'Airport', '3B', 'ON TIME', 'LOCAL                    ', '9439  ', '<_NEXT_MSG>02:25', 'Airport', '3B', 'ON TIME', 'LOCAL                    ', '441   ', '<_NEXT_MSG>02:55', 'Airport', '3B', 'ON TIME', 'LOCAL                    ', '9443  ', ''], ['R4N=01:35', 'Temple U', '2A', ' 3 LATE', 'LOCAL                    ', '9434  ', '<_NEXT_MSG>02:05', 'Warminster', '2A', 'ON TIME', 'LOCAL                    ', '436   ', '<_NEXT_MSG>02:35', 'Temple U', '2A', 'ON TIME', 'LOCAL                    ', '9438  ', '<_NEXT_MSG>03:05', 'Warminster', '2A', 'ON TIME', 'LOCAL                    ', '440   ', '']]  
new_list = [x[1] for x in current_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more pythonic way of doing it:

```py
trains = [x[1] for x in my_list_of_stuff]
```

This goes through each element of the `my_list_of_stuff` and takes the item in the second index, and adds it to `secondOnly`

This type of code is called list comprehension. You can read more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp